# Отправка формы с помощью ajax. Почему происходит редирект?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой jQuery код:

```
j$('#gen').submit(function(event){
        var postData = j$(this).serializeArray();
        alert(postData);
        var formURL = j$(this).attr("action");
        alert(formURL);
        j$.ajax(
        {
            url : "gen.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                //data: return data from server
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                //if fails
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        //event.stopPropagation();
        //event.cancelBubble();
        event.unbind();
        alert("clicked!");
        j$("#gen").submit();
      });
```

И есть форма с id="gen". Проблема в том, что все работает, но при нажатии кнопки "Submit" происходит редирект на страницу, которая указана в атрибуте action у формы. Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте event.preventDefault(); в самом начале или в самом конце. Также можно использовать

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что так работает форма. Попробуй для начала сделать return false, но это может не помочь. Если не поможет - перенеси весь код, скажем, в onclick по какой-нибудь кнопке, и submit вообще не используй.

И убери из попы функции `$("#gen").submit();`

Т.е. в данном случае ситуация ровно такая же как и при клике на ссылку. Т.е. обрабатывается click и вызываются click-колбэки, но после этого произойдет переход на href ссылки.